# iPad 2 running iOS 7 with Blue Yeti Mic

Tags: ipad, audio, ios, usb, microphone

I intend to buy a Blue Yeti microphone later today. I've been reading that you need two things for the yeti to work with GarageBand on iPad: the Apple Camera Connection kit (obvious really) and also a powered USB hub to avoid the 'device drawing too much power error.' I was wondering if this problem has been fixed with iOS 7 or not; do I Still need the USB Hub?

So, in short, my question is: Will I need to buy a powered USB hub to connect the Blue Yeti, or can I go straight through CCK without a hub?

Edit: Another question, will there be ANY sort of recording latency using this method or the Blue Spark Digital which is the other microphone I intend to look at. It's very important there is NO lag or latency when recording into the iPad

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late but for anyone else who may look for info on this:

I have used the Blue 'Yeti' to do quite a lot of recording into Garage Band on an iPad2.
  don't know anything about the other mic you mention but the Yeti is great for that price range in my experience.

I used a Belkin powered USB hub (+CC kit)as a work around successfully until one of the recent iPad updates (I haven't used the mic for awhile til recently so not sure which update), but now it doesn't work anymore.

the message "device draws to much power" or something, remains and the mic doesn't work...

didn't think to try without the hub in the chain..

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not a bug but a "feature". Apple doesn't want user to drain to much power from the connector.

Comment: So I believe! But my question is has this been changed in iOS 7, and will the yeti work?